# Numpy.mean returns different results for array and copy of array

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I have a problem that I could reduce to the following:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[98489.46, 98491.95000000001, 98496.93000000001,
98499.42000000001, 98504.40000000001, 98506.89000000001,
98511.87000000001, 98514.36000000002, 98519.34000000001,
98521.83], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], order='F')

Y = X.copy()
assert(np.array_equal(X, Y))

print(X.mean(axis=1)[0] - X[0, :].mean())

print(Y.mean(axis=1)[0] - Y[0, :].mean())
```

The first case prints `-1.4551915228366852e-11`, which I find unexpected. It basically says that the first row of the mean is different from the mean of the first row.

The second case prints `0`, which is expected in terms of the isolated result - but I had not expected this to be different from the first case, since `Y` is just a (memory-contiguous, I guess) copy of `X`.

Maybe all this is explainable by the order of summation, but what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Presumably the different expressions result in the mean being computed in different orders.  Floating point arithmetic is not guaranteed to be [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), so different orders of operations can produce different results.  Another example: compare `X[0,:].mean()` and `X[0,::-1].mean()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a.copy()` method is equivalent to `np.array(a)`. As stated from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html), to get a copy with the same memory layout, you should specify the `order` as:

```
Y = X.copy(order='F')
```

Functions like `mean` or `sum` have an inherent floating point precision which is likely the source of the error for that memory layout. I got 0 error using order 'K', 'A' or 'C' (numpy default)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, `Z = X.copy(order='F')` behaves like `X`, while `Y = X.copy()` behaves differently.